# How to display a chart centered (hor&vert) text on a tradingview pinescript chart

Tags: pine-script

How to disp a chart centered (hor&vert) text on a pinescript chart?
can't find anything in the documentation for that

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. Scripts have no visibility on the chart's visible number of bars or vertical scale, and no relative positioning is possible yet. The feature is being discussed but there is no ETA yet.